# Why are mounts with an active working directory "busy"?

Tags: mount, architecture

Linux appears not to mind if I move or delete a file or directory that is still in use by a process. So why does it complain if I try to unmount a device that is in use as a working directory by a process?

Example:

```
$ mkdir -p a b
$ sudo mount --bind a b
$ sh -c 'cd b; sleep 10' &
[1] 215679
$ sudo umount b
umount: /home/laktak/b: target is busy.
$
[1]+  Done                    sh -c 'cd b; sleep 10'
$ sudo umount b
$
```

As opposed to:

```
$ mkdir c
$ sh -c 'cd c; sleep 10; pwd; cd ..' &
[1] 220382
$ rmdir c
$
$ pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
$
[1]+  Done                    sh -c 'cd c; sleep 10; pwd; cd ..'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a distinct difference here: On a ext2/3/4 filesystem, "deleting" a file by its name means that the reference to the inode, i.e. the data structure where the file data is attached to, is removed (the filename you see in `ls` is merely a reference to that inode). A file is only considered "deleted" when the last such reference is gone (if you are interested, you can look into the concept of "hard links"). However, if you open a file, that act also creates a reference to that inode, so as long as the file is open, it is not actually "deleted" and the process that has the file open can still work with it.

The same holds true for an open directory. As long as you are still `cd`'d in the directory, the directory is still there, even if you deleted it from another shell instance. It is already in a "degraded" state however, and no longer accessible from other processes, and you cannot create new files in that directory even from the shell instance that is still there. (Notice by the way that I cannot reproduce the behavior you showed in your second example: when I run the same code in `bash` 4.3, `pwd` prints the directory name correctly even after it is deleted from the main shell instance).

Unmounting a device on the other hand is used to sever all connections to the files contained, and flushing all changes made, so the operating system will refuse to do so when someone is still "in there".

Comment: Thank you but why is the working directory of a mount more important? It's not even a open file. I've updated the question.

Comment: @laktak The process's current directory (and the root directory, and the executable being run) are essentially open files, even though you can't call close, etc. on them. The `lsof` and `fuser` commands can access and display them.

Comment: there is also the possibility that the now unmounted device is a physical device that the user may eject from the system (USB, CD/DVD, ...).